# Mic audio fine in everything but Webex

Tags: webex, evil, cisco-webex

I have my default audio settings on Windows 10. This means that the Communications tab in the Sound panel still has the "Reduce the volume of other sounds by 80%", I have mic boost at 0%, I have mic vol at 100%.

Calls on Slack, Discord, Skype, Teams are always fine. Webex however is giving me a really low mic volume. Others can hardly hear me after I call in (from abroad). Sometime though in small groups it's the other way round : one or two others are almost inaudible.

I am tempted to say this must be a Webex problem. I have sent off a tech support issue to them through their  interface (I hope - the UI is dire and there was no indication the issue was sent or received). Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Are you able to set up a local test where a user can physically tell you about the quality of sound they get?  The reason i suggest this is that I have had to use better external microphones for some group meetings. But that would affect more than just Webex - which is why I ask.

Comment: @John - Not sure I understand the question. Basically, on Slack, Skype, Discord , MS Teams - clients I use fairly often - there's no issue. With Webex , calling in to a foreign country (UK) via web (PC audio), the audio is nearly always inaudible to other listeners, sometimes inaudible to me and only for specific paritcipants.

Comment: The question was merely to assure that sound is loud (100% mic) or turned to normal for all but Webex, so that seems to make it their problem